# The Ajax element response is not accessible / undefined but it exists

Tags: ajax, undefined, element, response

I have this return of an ajax call:

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: urlAPI,
data: body,
success: function (result) {
..................
}

The result is:
{
"statusCode":200,
"statusMessage":"Success",
"statusApiReturn":{
"code":"0",
"msg":"Success",
"data":{
"appointCode":null,
"qrCodeImage":"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",
"visitorId":"143",
"appointRecordId":"104"
}
}
}

I need to access the qrCodeImage value, but when I use:
var qrCodeImage = result.statusApiReturn.data.qrCodeImage;

Im getting qrCodeImage = undefined

why if i have values in this field?

I try so many ways, the image exists and the error persists.

Comment: Hi, can you show complete ajax request ? Also ,did you parse your JSON before accessing value of it ?